# A regular expression to find URLs in a string

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

I want to find URLs such as `http://www.google.com` or `http://mail.yahoo.com.uk` from a string. What's the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a substring search or a validation question?

Comment: You do realize that almost anything is a valid URL?  The syntax is very flexible.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986.  The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be
   empty.  So `ftp:` is a legal URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> text = """I want to find url this "http://www.google.com" or "http://mail.yahoo.com.uk" from a string.

I tried different exprs but no one correct. Could anyone help me? Thanks
"""
>>> import re
>>> re.search( '(http://www\\.google\\.com)', text )
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02183060>
>>> _.groups()
('http://www.google.com',)
>>> re.search( '(http://mail\\.yahoo\\.com\\.uk)', text )
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x021830A0>
>>> _.groups()
('http://mail.yahoo.com.uk',)
>>> re.findall( '(http://[^"\' ]+)', text )
['http://www.google.com"', 'http://mail.yahoo.com.uk"']
```

Note that the last example is extremely simplified and should not be used in practice. Google for regular expressions for URLs if you want to do that.